# Convertible templated math vector

Tags: c++, coordinate-system, type-safety, casting

I've made a templated math vector struct with a templated type and templated dimension count.

I want my vectors to be convertible so I can easily make, for example, a `vec<int, 3>` from a `vec<float, 3>`

I want to do it in a safe way, or at least I'd like to know the ways it's unsafe.

I've never used `static_cast` or `dynamic_cast` and I've never used the `operator` user-defined conversion.

Here is what I came up with (only the relevant parts of the struct):

```
template<class t, size_t dimensions> struct vec{
    typedef t coord_type;       
    static constexpr size_t dimension_count = dimensions;

    std::array<coord_type, dimension_count> coords;

    template<class new_coord_type> operator vec<new_coord_type, dimension_count>() const{
        std::array<new_coord_type, dimension_count> casted_coords;
        std::transform(
            coords.begin(),
            coords.end(), 
            casted_coords.begin(),
            [](coord_type coord){return static_cast<new_coord_type>(coord);}
        );
        return {casted_coords};
    }
};
```

It seems to work how I want it to. For example, this compiles and gives me the correct results:

```
vec<float, 3> v1{1.1f, 2.5f, 3.9f};
vec<int, 3> v2 = v1; // converted correctly to {1, 2, 3}
```

The only way I could figure out how to cast the contents of an array is to use `std::transform`. I'm not sure if there's a better way.

Final questions: Is this unsafe or incorrect? How can this be improved?

Comment: If you are dealing with this type of mathematical vector, you may want to look at [`std::valarray`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/valarray)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had to adjust your code style a bit before I could easily read the code. In particular:

- Use `InitialCaps` for template parameters
- Add a space before `{`
- A newline after `template<...>` generally improves readability

Thus:

```
template<class T, size_t Dimensions>
struct vec {
    using coord_type = T;       
    static constexpr size_t dimension_count = Dimensions;

    std::array<T, Dimensions> coords;

    template<class U>
    operator vec<U, Dimensions>() const {
        std::array<U, Dimensions> casted_coords;
        std::transform(
            coords.begin(),
            coords.end(), 
            casted_coords.begin(),
            [](T coord) {
                return static_cast<U>(coord);
            }
        );
        return {casted_coords};
    }
};
```

Notice that I personally prefer to use the original template parameters `T`, `Dimensions`, etc. in places where your code used the member typedefs `coord_type`, `dimension_count` etc.; I find that this improves readability but I believe reasonable people may differ on the subject.

(In particular, the C++ Standard always uses member typedefs in declarations such as `reference operator*() const` as opposed to `T& operator*() const`; but I think that's because the name `reference` is part of the API of the class, whereas the name `T` is given for exposition only. That's a Standard-ism that we don't necessarily need to emulate when writing our own code.)

---

Nit: `Dimensions` is technically the wrong name for a *single* dimension. Also, by capitalizing the template parameter, we've freed up the shorter name `dimensions` (or `dimension`) for the constexpr member variable. You never have to use a tediously long name like `dimension_count` if you manage your naming real estate effectively!

---

```
        return {casted_coords};
```

The extra braces here are a pessimization; they inhibit move-elision (a.k.a. Named Return Value Optimization). Remove them... oh wait, I see, `casted_coords` is a `std::array`, not a `vec`! Why are you constructing a separate `array` and then copying it into the `vec`? That seems pointless!

At the very least, this should be

```
return { std::move(casted_coords) };
```

but ideally you'd define `casted_coords` to be of type `vec<U, Dimensions>` and then `transform` the data straight into `casted_coords.coords.begin()`.

---

```
            [](T coord) {
                return static_cast<U>(coord);
            }
```

This lambda takes its parameter by-copy, which is going to be expensive if `T` is, say, `std::string`. Prefer to take generic parameters by `const&` or (in C++14) by perfect-forward:

```
            [](const T& coord) {
                return static_cast<U>(coord);
            }

            [](auto&& coord) {
                return static_cast<U>(std::forward<decltype(coord)>(coord));
            }
```

In this case the former is better because it's less typing (and thus fewer chances to screw something up).

---

Your `operator vec<U, Dimensions>()` should be `explicit`, unless you have a darn good reason for it not to be. Most possible reasons I can think of do not qualify as "darn good."

---

In fact, I'd prefer to go further, and say that you shouldn't be using C++'s native "conversion" mechanisms for this kind of conversion at all. IMO you should write a user-defined function, along the lines of [`static_pointer_cast`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/pointer_cast) or [`any_cast`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/any/any_cast), that does precisely and explicitly what you want.

```
template<class To, class From, size_t Dim>
auto static_vec_cast(const vec<From, Dim>& from) -> vec<To, Dim> {
    vec<To, Dim> to;
    std::transform(
        from.coords.begin(),
        from.coords.end(), 
        to.coords.begin(),
        [](const From& x) {
            return static_cast<To>(x);
        }
    );
    return to;
}

int main() {
    vec<int, 3> a = {{1,2,3}};
    vec<float, 3> b = static_vec_cast<float>(a);
}
```

Season with SFINAE to taste.

---

However, this still has a major flaw: You're accidentally requiring that `To` be default-constructible! That's no good (especially if it *does* happen to be default-constructible but the default constructor is expensive). You can fix this issue, but it requires metaprogramming.

```
template<class To, class From, size_t Dim, size_t... Is>
auto static_vec_cast(const vec<From, Dim>& from, std::index_sequence<Is...>) -> vec<To, Dim> {
    vec<To, Dim> to = {{
        static_cast<To>(from.coords[Is])...
    }};
    return to;
}

template<class To, class From, size_t Dim>
auto static_vec_cast(const vec<From, Dim>& from) -> vec<To, Dim> {
    return static_vec_cast<To>(from, std::make_index_sequence<Dim>{});
}
```

The advantage of this approach is that it's hardly any more lines of code, but it's more correct, *and* it doesn't rely on running `std::transform` at runtime — it just generates the correct code directly inline.

Writing an efficient `static_vec_cast<U>(vec<T, Dim>&&)` is left as an exercise for the reader.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I find your answer very insightful. I don't think I disagree with anything. Answering in order, I had the typedefs because I wanted the template types to be members similar to `std::array::value_type`, but maybe it isn't' necessary. I like your coding style. I agree it's more readable. Idk why I'm not completely conforming to the standard library style, but I want to from now on. I love the idea of static_vec_cast. It reminds me of the  std::chrono::duration_cast. That is what I'll try. :)

Comment: Just one more point: This is one of the situations where ignoring "prefer composition over inheritance" pays huge dividends.

Comment: @Deduplicator: FWIW, I *probably* disagree (depending on what's in the part of the code the OP didn't show us); inheritance *almost always* sucks. For example, I doubt the OP wants `operator<` to work the same way it does for vectors; which means he's got to figure out the right syntax for overriding or `=delete`ing it. OTOH, if *all* the OP wanted was the `static_vec_cast` function, then he won't need `struct vec` at all and can get by with plain old `std::vector` — no composition *and* no inheritance! :)